# Export Localization missing strings in .xliff

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, xcode6

How does Xcode 6.4 (6E35b) choose what strings to include and exclude in the .xliff file created while exporting the development language? When I open the .xliff file, it has some strings from Localizable.strings but is definitely missing the majority of them. Some strings that were selected are towards the end of the file and others aren't. I can't figure out a pattern.

I've been manually adding strings that I use in code in Localizable.strings:

```
/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"New string" = "New string";
```

Is this not the correct way? Why is the export function ignoring some strings? They are not attributed.

Comment: You're not supposed to manually edit the .strings files. When you Export for Localisation, Xcode looks for instances of NSLocalizedString in your code and generates .strings files based on those.

Comment: Thanks! I think the problem is that I am using #defines for most of the NSLocalizedStrings in a header file and those aren't being picked up while exporting. I confirmed this by using an actual NSLocalizedString in a line where I used a #define, and sure enough it got put in the .xliff file. I wonder if I can make it work with #defines.

Comment: This is not possible without an additional shell script... NSLocalizedStrings need raw string literals to work properly.

Comment: I ended up correctly formatting my giant list of strings with vim and putting them in an NSLog that I removed after exporting. Thanks!